# use ngStorage values in the template of site

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

I've got a site that uses [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)  to save cart data until checkout, when it is then stored in the database.  When using vm.$storage = $localStorage; in my controller, I can access the cart information easily for the part of the page in the  section of index.html but I WANT to be able to access and display information from ngStorage in the header of my site, which is nested inside .

I've tried adding ng-controller="SiteController" to my li tag but still don't get anything to display that way.

How can I get the localStorage using ngStorage to display in the template (index.html) of my site?

My index.html file is setup something like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
// a bunch of code to show my other navigation
// code to show my shopping cart at a glance
    <li class="quick-cart">
        <a href="#">
        <span class="badge badge-aqua btn-xs badge-corner">
             {{vm.$storage.cart.items.length}}
        </span>
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
        </a>
        <div class="quick-cart-box">
            <h4>Shop Cart</h4>
        <div class="quick-cart-wrapper">
           <a href="#"><!-- cart item -->
              <h6>Item Name</h6>
              <small>$12.34</small>
           </a><!-- /cart item -->

            <!-- cart no items example -->
            <!--<a class="text-center" href="#"><h6>0 ITEMS ON YOUR CART</h6></a>-->
        </div>
        <!-- quick cart footer -->
        <div class="quick-cart-footer clearfix">
        <a href="shop-cart.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">VIEW CART</a>
        <span class="pull-left"><strong>TOTAL:</strong> $54.39</span>
        </div>
        <!-- /quick cart footer -->
        </div>
    </li>
//other code between the header and controller content
<div ng-view></div> //the CONTENT section controlled by each controller
//other code to finish the page
```

My site-controller.js code is:

```
/* global angular */ angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('SiteController', SiteController);


function SiteController($route, $routeParams, AuthFactory, jwtHelper, $window, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.$storage = $localStorage;
    vm.$storage.cart = vm.$storage.cart;
    console.log(vm.$storage.cart);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `controllerAs` syntax in controller you need to use the `as alias` in `ng-controller`

```
ng-controller="SiteController as vm"
```

This defines the `vm` you are already using in the view for:

```
{{vm.$storage.cart.items.length}}
```